# Accessing GPRS (quectel m95) data through web server (asp.net query string method for retrieve data)

Tags: webserver, gprs

I am trying to send some data to web server through GPRS (quectel m95),

asp.net web server to retrieve GPRS data by using query string method.

For connection to the web

```
AT+QIOPEN="TCP","www.mywebsite.in",80
```

and reply,

```
OK
CONNECT OK
```

to sending data,

```
AT+QISEND
```

reply,

```
>
```

then actual data,

```
POST /TTracking/GettingGPSDataWebForm.aspx?Value=%053106.000,A,09.46467,N,080.92963,E,241212$
```

reply,

```
SEND OK

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

CLOSED
```

Content not updated to data base, PC side data retrieved by using query string method. Is there any other configuration need to send or retrieve data.

Is my QISEND method is correct?

Domain connection reply says CONNECT OK and sending of data reply also SEND OK.

```
POST /Rajtest/Test/Ter/newpay.php?value=15*between1*11/12/2013*12:13:15*12.5$
```

above Php page working fine.

"TTracking/GettingGPSDataWebForm.aspx" this web page hosted in local server and "www.mywebsite.in" is redirected to my local web server.

i am new to one, so pls help me thanks....

Answer (score 0):

have you tried specifying a different port for example set up port 350. I had read somewhere on https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2016/09/25/gsm-connecting-to-a-server-on-a-port-by-tcpip-part-1/

to avoid using the http port 80 as it uses a different protocol.